# GPS MODULE DATA - solution?

Tags: c, gps, stm32

Here are the datas that we receive from GNSS module:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64
//$GaabL,,,,,,V,N*5D
char Received[] = { "Odetnij to jak mozesz$GaabL,,,,,,V,N*5D" };

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    int b;
    int c;
    int super_atoi;
    int wynik;
    int xor = 0;

    while (Received[i] != '$')
    {
        printf("%c", Received[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    printf("%c\n ");
    while (Received[i] != '*')
    {
        printf("%c", Received[i]);
        xor ^= Received[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n XOR      = %d", xor);
    printf("\n XOR w hex    = %#02x  ", xor);
    printf("\n XOR w dec    = %d ", xor);

    if (Received[i] == '*')
    {
        i++;
        b = Received[i];
        printf("\n 1 znak w kodzie za * =  %c", b);
        i++;
        c = Received[i];
        printf("\n 2 znak w kodzie za * =  %c", c);
    }
    char a[3] = { b, c };
    super_atoi = atoi(a);
    super_atoi = strtol(a, NULL, 16);
    printf("\n ATOI      = %s  ", a, super_atoi);

    if (xor == super_atoi)
    {
        printf("%c\n ");
        printf("\n WORKING!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c\n ");
        printf("\n not working");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To count the sumcheck of each we've got to xor char's between "$" and "*". My program for that is:

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/pV7FnK)

Basically we check each char if its "$" then xor elements till we receive *.
However i've small problem... I need to check every single line of data - NEO-7 transmit pack of [280]+ chars each certain period of time, which include 11"$: and 11 *.  There are two ways of checking everything that i can think of:

1. Checking every single byte (char), start counting when "$" appears, finishes when * appears, compare the results with 2 elements after "*".
2. (More suitable for my program) Receive array[35] from GPS module, create seperate array in which i will include what's left from previous sumcheck, put next pack of data that arrives from GPS, repeat. Could you please tell me what's better? also How to create these solutions?

Comment: Why `array[35]`? NMEA messages can be up to 82 bytes long. IMHO, it is better to receive and process message by message. Wait for `$` then store whole message until `<LF>` received. Process message and get next (some ring buffer for UART bytes may be needed). Or collect messages in UART handler,  put received message into message queue and collect next message.

Comment: I disagree.  Receiving the chars one-by-one, loading them into a message, communicating the message to some thread or whatever, then iterating the message byte-by-byte to parse the protocol is wasteful and avoidable.  The bytes already come in 'iterated', so why not process them in a state-machine as they are extracted from the UART FIFO?